# Бредовые задания от Яндекса

Tags: стилистика

Скажите, пожалуйста, какую "логику" вкладывали авторы-составители в данное задание?

Какой из перечисленных вариантов является предпочтительным с точки зрения стилистики?

> Если фильтры активны — блок имеет яркий зеленый цвет.
> Если неактивны — блок имеет светлый серый цвет.

> Блок с активными фильтрами имеет зеленый цвет.
> Блок с неактивными фильтрами подсвечивается серым.

> Если фильтры активны — блок зеленый.
> Если неактивны — серый.

> Если фильтры активны, блок будет зеленым.
> Если фильтры неактивны, блок будет серым.

> Фильтры включены — блок яркий зеленый, выключены — блок серый.

Как показана эта "стилистическая разница"? Для меня есть только примеры, в которых присутствует речевая избыточность. Выбор же одного единственного варианта из перечисленных (в плане стилистики) — бред.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какую логику могли вкладывать:
1) есть ли избыточность;
2) всё ли звучит;
3) есть ли что-то разговорное;
4) есть ли повторения слов, которых следовало бы избежать;
5) нет ли резкости.

Слово "имеет" не звучит — два варианта отпадают.
"Будет зелёным" — разговорный вариант, он же, насколько понимаю, сразу зелёный, а не будет таким в будущем. Да и там "фильтры" повторяется (это плохо).
Последний вариант сильно резкий. "Яркий зеленый" — похоже на опечатку.

Третий вариант самый удачный.